# Unexpected empty result from shell script that calls awk

Tags: shell, awk

Below is the sample shell script, Here the value of NF is coming Null instead of 9 (the output of expression on line 4)

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
VAR="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
NF=`echo $VAR | awk '{PRINT NF}'`
echo "$NF"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: the function is `print` **not**  `PRINT`

Comment: Thanks Jay, sorry  as you answer is in comment so I cannot select your answer as the accepted answer even though you were the first one to correctly answer. Thank you for the guidance and your time.  

Regards,
Sambhav

Comment: No worries, glad you got everything working. `;)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWK is case-sensitive.  You want the function `print`.

By writing `PRINT NF` instead, AWK interprets that as the names of two variables, concatenated.  `PRINT` has an empty value; `NF` has the value "9".  You didn't ask it to do anything with the result (such as printing it), so the AWK script produces no output for that line of input.

Answer (score 2):

The command you're looking for is `print`, not `PRINT`. Awk is case-sensitive.

Also, it is recommended to use the following command substitution: `$(...)` instead of backticks (`` ` ``).

So in your case:

```
NF=$(echo $VAR | awk '{print NF}')
```

Comment: Also recommended to double quote variables. `echo "$VAR"`

Comment: Thank you :), Yes Chirag ..`` is deprecated $(..) is advisable 

Yes Jotne we should double quote the variables to prevent globbing.

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained what was wrong with your code. I would like to suggest another way to count the number of words:

```
var="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
wc -w <<<"$var"
```

Or on older shells:

```
echo "$var" | wc -w
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, for new alternative answer I checked it and it is working exactly as expected.

Comment: It depends whether you want to count words per line or total words in the whole string. For the one-line example, they happen to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it (using Here String).  PS always double quote variable like this `"$var"`

```
NF=$(awk '{print NF}' <<< "$var")
```